# ClickHouse create table returns excess symbol

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I execute this SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
    `year_month` UInt32,
    some_sum AggregateFunction(sumMap, Tuple(Array(String), Array(Int64)))
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree
ORDER BY (`year_month`);
```

But when I open the DDL of the table I get:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
    year_month UInt32,
    some_sum AggregateFunction(1, sumMap, Tuple(Array (String), Array(Int64)))
)
ENGINE = AggregatingMergeTree ORDER BY year_month
        SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

Why do I get excess symbol `1` in `AggregateFunction`?

Answer (score 1):

It's an AggregateFunction versioning.

Clickhouse sometimes changes the internal representation of how AggregateFunction stores state in the table. It breaks/corrupts user data after upgrade Clickhouse server, because data stored in a table by the old version became unreadable for the new version of Clickhouse.
To solve this issue the AggregateFunction versioning was introduced.

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/12552

https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/24820